# @ExceptionHandler called *after* finally block in Spring @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE to create a REST API. My controller validates incoming data and throws a MyRequestValidationException. This is handled by an @ExceptionHandler.

But when test my code, I find that the @ExceptionHandler is invoked *after* the finally {} block.

Is this expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong ? Shouldn't the finally block be the final thing called?

```
@RestController
public class MyAPI {
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public AuthenticationResponse authenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)  {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        this.logStartAPI(servletRequest, authenticationRequest);
        ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().set(HttpStatus.OK);

        .
        .
        .

        // This throws a Runtime exception RequestValidationException
        authenticationRequest.validate();

        .
        .
    } finally {
        this.logEndAPI(servletRequest, startTime, ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().get());
        ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().remove();
    }
}
```

And this is my ExceptionHandler (in @ControllerAdvice class).

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { MyRequestValidationException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyRequestValidationException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("RequestValidationException", ex);
    ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().set(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

Comment: How would it be called before the `finally` block in the _throwing_ code?

Comment: Spring MVC registers the `@ExceptionHandler` method as an `ExceptionHandler`. After invoking your `@RequestMapping` handler method, it check if it threw an exception. If it did, it tries to find and use an `ExceptionHandler` that can handle it. By then, execution has left the handler method code. Spring doesn't inject code anywhere it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ExceptionHandler` is like `try-catch` over all your method, it will work similar as:

```
@RestController
public class MyAPI {
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public AuthenticationResponse authenticationRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)  {
try {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        this.logStartAPI(servletRequest, authenticationRequest);
        ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().set(HttpStatus.OK);

        .
        .
        .

        // This throws a Runtime exception RequestValidationException
        authenticationRequest.validate();

        .
        .
    } finally {
        this.logEndAPI(servletRequest, startTime, ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().get());
        ThreadLocalStaticClass.getThreadLocalHttpStatus().remove();
    }
} catch(MyRequestValidationException e) {
   //handling of your exception
}
}
```

so now I think you understand why you have such behavior.